# Find all views containing specific table names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several views in my database that are built on tables.

Is it possible to query for view names which contain specific tables in it?

For example by using:

```
Where tablename like '%TableA%'
```

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%TableA%'
```

But this gives list of tables created using this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query to search views for a table:

```
SELECT Objects.name, Modules.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules AS Modules INNER JOIN sys.objects AS Objects ON         
Modules.object_id = Objects.object_id
WHERE definition like '%TableA%'
```